# How to Prevent Multiple entries stored in database?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Consider am using java  , struts, hibernate and oracle. How can i prevent duplicate entries stored in database. One way is to make field as Unique . For example i am entering country "USA" in jsp page,USA is already available means how can i prevent it. Please let me know.

Regards,

sara

Answer (score 3):

You should always indeed put a unique constraint on fields which must stay unique. This will, however, lead to a cryptic exception at commit time. If you want to be more user-friendly, you should check if the entry already exists (using a query) before inserting it, and display a useful and readable error message to the user if the entry already exists.

This still allows two concurrent users to check at the same time, then insert at the same time, but it greatly reduces the probability, and the unique constraint makes sure that one of the commits will fail, leaving your database in a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Query your database whether it already contains *USA* or not. If it does, then don't store it. If not, then do.

Comment: @user964802: read the documentation, it's full of examples: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql. That's what real programmers do to learn a technology: they read the documentation.

Comment: Please write some code and ask a specific question. As others here pointed out, a unique constraint is still necessary to ensure data integrity in case your code does not prevent duplicate insertions in the first place (e.g. caused by concurrency)

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique index to your database table on the country column.

Additionally you can annotate the country attribute of your hibernate object with `@Column(unique=true)`.